# Unable to install nvm on Mac

Tags: command-line, nvm

I used the following command to install nvm on Mac:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

It did execute successfully but when I use

```
nvm install 10
```

command to install version 10, it throws an error stating -
zsh: command not found: nvm

I don't know how to fix this issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the lines to your .zshrc/.bashrc file and open a new terminal window? nvm installs as shell-script alias and needs a new terminal to be opened.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Comment: Exactly, all I had to do is create a .zshrc and add this export command in it.